# ipython 2.7.15+ -> 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

Im new to python, only used C before. I use ubuntu 18.04.
Anyways, a buddy of mine gave me the tip to get ipython to test commands so I installed it by "pip install ipython" but I only got v2.7.15+, both ipython and ipython2 are this version.
I've tried to search around for a solution but can't find anything. Anyone knows what to do?

Comment: Do you have a python 3+ installation?

Comment: I think so, I compile my programs with "python3 ./....py" but I don't have a ipython3, the version of my python3 is 3.6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have python3 installed, simply use:
`python3 -m pip install ipython`

`-m` is for module:

> When called with -m module-name, the given module is located on the Python module path and executed as a script.

From [Command line and environment @ Interface options](https://docs.python.org/3.1/using/cmdline.html#interface-options)

EDIT:
try doing:
`pip3 install ipython`
If that doesn't work, try doing:
`sudo apt install python3-pip`
Then one of the above.

Comment: It says "usr/bin/python3: no module named pip"

Comment: Can you try doing `pip3 install ipython`?

Comment: @JimmyGustavsson yay! I'm happy for you :) If it was helpful you are more than welcome to mark my question as the answer, the checkmark next to my question and upvote :)